# dynamic object creation and assignment using reflection

Tags: java, object, reflection, instance, variable-assignment

I'm loading a class with following statement:

```
Class classToLoad = Class.forName("com.somePackage.SomeotherPackage.classname" );
```

Later i wd use reflection to get the methods of this class. now for invoking the methods with methodname.invoke() function i'd require the object of the loaded class. thus i want to create the object of the loaded class. I try to do it this way:

```
Object obj = classToLoad.newInstance();
```

but the problem in this is that this way i don't get the object of the class loaded but i get object of Object class.

Now if i want to call the functions of the loaded class, i do it like:

```
methodName.invoke(obj);
```

it throws an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class

can anybody please help?

Update on the problem:

The problem is that i need the left hand side of the assignment to be of a different class type and that class type will be decided on run time

For the below statement:

Object instance = clazz.newInstance();

"instance" should be of the "clazz" type and not the "Object" class.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Well, it sounds like you've got the wrong method. Please show a short but *complete* example.

Comment: `classToLoad.newInstance();` returns new instance of class "stored" int `classToLoad`. You can check it by printing `obj.getClass()` so your problem must be hidden somewhere else. As Jon suggested you should show us some code that we could use to reproduce your error or we can only guess what could go wrong.

Comment: What you are trying to do is usually solved by having an abstract parent class that defines an abstract method and you can use that for the interface to all subclasses: `AbstractParentClass obj = (AbstractParentClass) classToLoad.newInstance();`

Answer (score 0):

It works fine when everything's set up correctly:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

class Foo {

    public Foo() {
    }

    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}

public class Test {    

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("Foo");
        Method method = clazz.getMethod("sayHello");
        Object instance = clazz.newInstance();

        method.invoke(instance); // Prints Hello
    }
}
```

My guess is that the method you've fetched (`methodName`) wasn't actually fetched from `classToLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just cast the return type and invoke the method directly.

```
public class Foo{
    void HelloReflection(){
        System.out.println("Hello reflection");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            Foo o = (Foo) Class.forName("Foo").newInstance();
            o.HelloReflection();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
```

This can be thrown if the method has no arguments and not found in your object's class. Probably You are calling the invoke method on the wrong object or your fetched method is wrong for your object.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that i need the left hand side of the assignment to be of a different class type and that class type will be decided on run time. ... How can i achieve this?

Use some language other than Java. Java is statically typed, which basically means you're not allowed to do exactly what you just asked how to do. The other answers here correctly show how to invoke a method without knowing the type of an object at compile time, but you'll never be able to set the type of a variable at runtime.